# Distinct values of logarithm with base and value $\leq N$

Tags: logarithms

I am trying to solve the following question:

Consider the set $S_N=\{\log_a b | 2\leq a,b \leq N\}$. How many distinct values are there inside $S_N$?

For example, $S_5={log_22,log_23,log_24,log_25,log_32,log_33,log_34,log_35,...,log_55}$
In which $log_22=log_33=log_44=log_55$, so the answer for $N=5$ would be 13

I currently have no idea on how to do it so any ideas would be helpful, thanks

Comment: Have you considered when $\log_ab=\log_cd$?

Comment: When $b=a^e$ and $d=c^e$, but is there any easier way of expressing that?